# Keep functionality of return key but disable "\n" IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Update: **Return Key Issue**

I am using the return key in the TextView to send a message.

However, when I press the return key(which i changed to "Send") the "\n" feature is still enabled. How can i disable the newline feature without ruining my functionality of "Send".

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn  range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (text == "\n") {

                if(message.text != ""){
                message.text = nil
                doSomething()
            }

        }
        return true
    }
```

Tried to toggle Auto-enable return key still doesn't take care of my problem.

I need to access **doSomething()** the same way but without "\n" effecting my textView after I clear the message.

Comment: I already tried that. I get the same thing

Comment: Can you explain more how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Completely blanked and updated the post.

Comment: Return false instead of true.

Comment: If you are not allowing more than one line of text, why not use a `UITextField` instead of a `UITextView`?

Comment: Also note that your code will fail if the user pastes in multiple lines of text.

Comment: Does not fail actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning `true`. That means "go ahead and enter the return character that the user typed". But this is exactly what you say you do *not* want to do. Return `false` instead (for the case where `text == "\n"`).

Answer (score 0):

Call cursorPosition() function after

```
message.text = nil 
message.text = ""
```

and add the following function

```
 func cursorPosition() {
    let startPosition = textView.beginningOfDocument
    textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: startPosition, to: startPosition)
}
```

Comment: this did not fix it

Comment: try returning false